# Alternate color coding in HTML table of MySQL results in shell script

Tags: html, mysql, shell, awk

I am using a MySQL query in a shell script to get some data. Query is like:

```
mysql -h$host -u$user -p$pass -H --skip-column-names $database -e "Some_query.sql`" > temp_file
```

The -H option gives  the results in HTML table format but in a single line. The result is in the following format:

```
<TR><TD>2014-03-05</TD><TD>3.869</TD><TD>10.654</TD><TD>6.874</TD><TD>19.194</TD><TD>5.716</TD><TD>15.875</TD></TR><TR><TD>2014-03-04</TD><TD>3.571</TD><TD>10.054</TD><TD>7.874</TD><TD>22.037</TD><TD>5.788</TD><TD>16.432</TD></TR><TR><TD>2014-03-03</TD><TD>3.311</TD><TD>9.180</TD><TD>7.280</TD><TD>20.510</TD><TD>5.533</TD><TD>15.475</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

I am trying to give alternate color code to the rows generated as the MySql reqult.

Comment: One would normally do that with css

Comment: I am not sure how to incorporate it in shell script. Also, the results come at once, in a single line, not row by row. Otherwise I'd have used awk NR

Comment: So what's all this TR, TD stuff?

Comment: These are HTML tags for row and columns. The -H option in MySQL gives results in HTML ready format. I use the file contents as input to the mail. Mail is generated in HTML format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

`cat MySQL_query_result_in_tabular_format.txt | awk '{if (NR % 2 == 1) print "<tr style=\"background:#CCCCCC\"><td>" $1 "</td><td align=\"right\">" $2 "</td><td align=\"right\">" $3 "</td></tr>";else print "<tr style=\"background:#FFFFFF\"><td>" $1 "</td><td align=\"right\">" $2 "</td><td align=\"right\">" $3 "</td></tr>";}' >> HTML_formatted_output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps because I can't see your sql, but here's something to think about...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @i:= ABS(@i-1) THEN 'white' ELSE 'black' END colour
     , recipe FROM recipes, (SELECT @i := 0) var 
 ORDER 
    BY recipe;
+--------+-------------------------+
| colour | recipe                  |
+--------+-------------------------+
| white  | Beans on Toast          |
| black  | Cheese & Beans on Toast |
| white  | Cheese on Toast         |
| black  | Macaroni & Cheese       |
| white  | Toast & Jam             |
+--------+-------------------------+
```